# Can't get colors from constants React

Tags: reactjs, components, constants

I am writing an admin dashboard with typescript react and tailwind, have an file for constants and am mapping over them in a component.

salesInfoBoxes - constants export
SalesInfoBox - reusable box component

Problem:
When using the SalesInfoBox component and adding the bg from the constant it works, I see it in the dev tools, but the color is not actually added

Any help?

```
 {salesInfoBoxes.map((box, index) => (
        <SalesInfoBox
          heading={box.heading}
          qty={box.qty}
          bg={box.bg}
          key={index}
        />
      ))}
```

```
const SalesInfoBox = ({
  heading,
  qty,
  bg,
}: {
  heading: string
  qty: number
  bg: string
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-white w-[200px] mx-auto rou-t mb-[30px] rou-b">
      <div className="h-[30px] bg-gray-300 text-center rou-t">{heading}</div>
      <div className={`bg-[${bg}] h-[200px] flex flex-col text-center`}>
        <span className="sctOneNumbers mt-[30px]">{qty}</span>
        <span>Valued</span>
        <span className="bg-[#bbb] py-1 px-2 rou w-fit mx-auto">
          ${qty * 500}
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SalesInfoBox
```

Constant I'm taking data from

```
export const salesInfoBoxes = [
  {
    heading: "Not delivered",
    qty: 7,
    bg: "#F0FF96",
  },
  {
    heading: "In cart",
    qty: 170,
    bg: "#F0FF96",
  },
  {
    heading: "Returned",
    qty: 1,
    bg: "#FF9696",
  },
]
```

I see I have the directories in tailwind.config.js I tried multiple ways of solving the problem, none worked.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your `SalesInfoBox` component, you're using string interpolation within the `className` for the background color:```<div className={`bg-[${bg}] h-[200px] flex flex-col text-center`}>``` . Instead of using string interpolation here, you should directly provide the bg value without interpolation: ```<div className={`bg-${bg} h-[200px] flex flex-col text-center`}>```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to do it like that, by adding square brackets in the constants and removing them from the SalesInfoBox, still didn't get it

Comment: Make sure that you have set up Tailwind CSS correctly in your project and that the custom color values you're using (#F0FF96 and #FF9696) are defined in your Tailwind configuration file. Also, As a test, try applying the background color directly without using Tailwind's dynamic classes. For example, <div style={{ backgroundColor: bg }} ...>. This will help verify if the issue is specific to Tailwind or if there's something else causing the problem

Comment: It worked, adding bg as an inline style for the background made the change, so what now?